# Problem with execution async method

Tags: multithreading, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, asynchronous

I have a problem with this code

```
 if(Handlers.Count==0)
                {
                    GetHandlers();
                    while (_handlers.Count == 0)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                    }
                }
                return _showroomLogs;
```

This method executes:

```
 private void GetHandlers()
        {
            WebSerive.GetHandlersCompleted += new EventHandler<GetHandlersCompletedEventArgs>(OnGetHandlersCompleted);
            WebSerive.GetHandlersAsync(_app.HandlerId);
        }
```

but to this method:

```
private void OnGetHandlersCompleted(object sender, GetHandlersCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            WebSerive.GetHandlersCompleted -= new EventHandler<GetHandlersCompletedEventArgs>(OnGetHandlersCompleted);
            _handlers = e.Result;
        }
```

I fall into afterd execution of

```
return _showroomLogs;
```

of cource if I remove this piece with While

What I must to do, to have executed OnGetHandlersAsync before

```
 return _showroomLogs;
```

?

Comment: You can't.  That's what async means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recognise that as soon as you introduce an asynchronous operation to a sequence the whole sequence becomes asynchronous.  Using blocking techniques like `Sleep` is 99.99999% the wrong choice.

Restructure as:-

```
  private void GetHandlers(int handlerID, Action<IList<Handler>> returnResult)
  {
        EventHandler<GetHandlersCompletedEventArgs> eh = null;
        eh = (s, args) =>
        {
             WebSerive.GetHandlersCompleted -= eh;
             returnResult(args.Result);
        };
        WebSerive.GetHandlersCompleted += eh;
        WebSerive.GetHandlersAsync(handerlID);
 }
```

you then call with:-

```
 GetHandlers(_app.HandlerId, handlers =>
 {
      _handlers = handlers;
      // Do other stuff 
 });
```

**Edit**

Let me outline at a conceptual level what the fundemental problem is here.  Lets say I have button click event, which calls `FuncA`.  `FuncA` calls `FuncB`, `FuncB` calls `FuncC`.

> click -> FuncA -> FuncB -> FuncC

This whole sequence is synchronous it might look like:-

```
 void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     FuncA();
     //Do other stuff
 }

 void FuncA()
 {
     var result = FuncB();
     //Do stuff with result;
 }

 string FuncB()
 {
     return FuncC() + " World";
 }

 string FuncC()
 {
     return "Hello";
 }
```

But now lets change `FuncC` into something that operates asynchronously.  It returns immediately but its return value is not available until later, it calls a callback method when done that carries the result as parameter.  The problem for `FuncB` is that it wants to return a value but can't until the async operation of `FuncC` has completed.  Rather than have `FuncB` block the thread, we need to turn `FuncB` into an asynchronous operation in the same manner as `FuncC`.  This whole process needs to bubble all the way to the event.  It becomes:-

```
 void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     FuncA(() =>
     {
         //Do other stuff after FuncA has completed
     });
 }

 void FuncA(Action callback)
 {
     FuncB(result =>
     {
         //Do stuff with result
         // then finally
         callback();
     });
 }

 void FuncB(Action<string> returnResult)
 {
     FuncC(result => returnResult(result + " World"));
 }

 void FuncC(Action<string> returnResult)
 {
     Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => returnResult("Hello"));
 }
```

This pattern will do when there is only one actual asynchronous operation involved.  Things start to get really funky when you have a series of actual async calls to make within the same operation. To avoid excessive callback nesting a little framework help is needed.  I call mine the `AsyncOperationService` which you can read about [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2010/09/12/simple-asynchronous-operation-runner-ndash-part-1.aspx).

Comment: unfortunately I have the same situation like before:/

Comment: @user278618: Yes you will be, you have to take the pattern I've outlined all the way back to originating event.